# Matlab return vector

Tags: matlab, octave

Sorry for the beginners matlab question...

```
function [ A B C ] = crunch(i)
  A = i^2;
  B = 2*A;
  C = A+B;
end;

vals = zeros(5,3);
  for i=1:5
    vals(i,:) = crunch(i);
  endfor;
disp(vals);
```

This is not the result I expected.

```
vals =
 1 1 1
 4 4 4
 9 9 9
 ..... etc
```

if I instead explicitiy place A, B & C in a row vector and return that, then everything is fine.

```
function retval = crunch(i)
  A = i^2;
  B = 2*A;
  C = A+B;
  retval = [ A B C ];
end;

ans = 
  1    2    3
  4    8   12
  9   18   27
 16   32   48
 25   50   75
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Using the first version of crunch this would also produce the correct value:

vals = zeros(5,3);
  for i=1:5
    [vals(i,1),vals(i,2),vals(i,3)] = crunch(i);
  end
disp(vals);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MATLAB is generally reluctant to give you multiple return values unless you explicitly ask for them. So in the first version, when you do:

```
vals(i,:) = crunch(i);
```

What MATLAB does is take just the first return value from `crunch(i)`, then broadcast that to all the elements of `vals(i,:)`. It’s like doing:

```
return_val = crunch(i);
vals(i,:) = return_val;
```

If you explicitly ask MATLAB for multiple return values, you get the desired behavior. As @igon notes, this version will fix the behavior:

```
[vals(i,1), vals(i,2), vals(i,3)] = crunch(i);
```

Or, I think if `vals` were a cell array, `vals{i, :} = crunch(i);` would work too, but that doesn’t make sense in this case — using a regular (not cell) array seems like the right approach in your code.